# Why MVC gives me 404 not found when 2 parts of url marked as UrlParameter.Optional

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string email, string password)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(email, password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or password");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
}
```

The HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.Path.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                return View();
            }
            if (Request.Url != null)
            {
                return RedirectPermanent(Request.Url + " /");
            }
            return View();

        }
    }
```

Routing is like that

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{email}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , email=UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
```

But when i put the application on IIS and i run it gives me 404 not found when navigating to root of the site (I'd expect it to match the route that redirects to HomeController.Index Action)

Comment: an [mcve] would be great!

Comment: What is in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: @James R. http://localhost/WebApp%20/

Comment: @JamesR. But in requested url is  http://localhost:80/WebApp /

Answer (score 0):

It's the space (%20) that you are appending to the URL. On the line:

```
return RedirectPermanent(Request.Url + " /");
```

You could remove that space, but then you'll probably get a recursive redirect. It's not quite clear to me what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Ok...but it not allows me to modify @James R.

Comment: Not sure what that means. What is the purpose of adding the space?

Comment: Is not the space with or whithout him is the same

Comment: Maybe there is another issue then. Because I can guarantee you that if you put `%20` on the end of a URL to a standard plain old MVC controller action, you'll get a 404.